# Facebook - Error Code - 2500 Inactive Access Token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am using Parse (by Facebook) as my back end services and I have linked Facebook with the existing Parse User.

I am using the following code on an ParseUser linked with Facebook

```
  accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
  Log.d("Access Token",accessToken.getToken());

   new GraphRequest(
            accessToken,"/me?fields=first_name,last_name",null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback(){

                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse){

                    if(graphResponse.getError()!=null)
                        Log.d("Error", graphResponse.getError().toString());

                    else{
                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject = graphResponse.getJSONObject();
                            ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                            user.put("email",jsonObject.getString("email"));
                            user.saveInBackground();

                        }catch(JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Now in my log I am getting an access token which when used at developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  -> It works completely fine there

In my log I am getting the following **Error** ->   "{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}"

This is totally frustrating. I am using the same token to access my information and it is working completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something and it worked.

Changed the following line

```
 new GraphRequest(
        accessToken,"/me?fields=first_name,last_name",null,...
```

To

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("fields","first_name,last_name");
 new GraphRequest(
        accessToken,"/me",bundle,
```

And it worked !